Hilbert space map with closed image respects closed subspaces?
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces, and $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded linear operator with closed image. Is it true that for every closed subspace $M \subseteq X$, that $T(M)$ will be closed in $Y$? I’m struggling to prove this is true, but I’m also failing to find a counter example.
The best idea I have had in trying to prove the result is to use the following lemma:
Lemma: Let $L: A \rightarrow B$ be a bounded linear map of Hilbert spaces. Then $\text{im}(L) \subseteq B$ is closed if and only if there is a real constant $c > 0$ such that $c ||a|| \leq ||La||$ for all $a \in (\ker L)^\perp$.
Viewing $M$ as a Hilbert space, we can try to prove that the restriction $T \rvert_M: M \rightarrow Y$ has closed image using the lemma. The issue I’m having with this approach is I don’t see any guarantee that the orthogonal complement of $\ker(T_M)$ (inside of of $M$) is contained in the orthogonal complement of $T$ (inside of $X$).
Any help would be appreciated! And if there is a counter example, is there a nice characterization of maps that send closed subspaces to closed subspaces?

This is false. For example, let $X = l^2 \oplus l^2$, $Y = l^2$, and $T: X \to Y$ be the orthogonal projection onto the first summand. Let $M = \overline{\mathrm{span}}\{(\frac{1}{n}e_n, \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n}e_n): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Since $\{(\frac{1}{n}e_n, \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n}e_n): n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $M$, we have $M = \{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(\frac{1}{n}e_n, \frac{\sqrt{n^2-1}}{n}e_n): (a_n)_n \in l^2\}$. Thus, $T(M) = \{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}e_n: (a_n)_n \in l^2\} \subset l^2$, which is dense in $l^2$ (it contains all finitely supported sequences) but not the entire $l^2$ ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}e_n \notin T(M)$, for example), so $T(M)$ is not closed.
By applying an isomorphism (not an isometric isomorphism, just a bounded bijective linear map), we see that the above example implies the result is false whenever $T$ has infinite-dimensional range and infinite-dimensional kernel (i.e., whenever $\mathrm{im}(T)$ and $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ are both infinite-dimensional). Note that when $\mathrm{im}(T)$ is finite-dimensional, the result is clearly true as all subspaces of a finite-dimensional space are closed. The same holds when $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ is finite-dimensional. For this, we prove the following: let $M \subset X$ be a nontrivial closed subspace which intersects with $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ trivially and let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\mathrm{ker}(T)^\perp$, then there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\|Px\| \geq C\|x\|$ for all $x \in M$. Assume to the contrary. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)_n \subset M$ of unit vectors s.t. $Px_n \to 0$. Note that $x_n - Px_n$ are vectors of norm bounded by $1$ in the finite-dimensional space $\mathrm{ker}(T)$, whence by passing to a subsequence we may assume $x_n - Px_n \to y$ for some $y \in \mathrm{ker}(T)$. But then $x_n = (x_n - Px_n) + Px_n \to y$. $M$ is closed, so $y \in M$. But then as $M \cap \mathrm{ker}(T) = \{0\}$, we have $y = 0$, which constradicts the fact that all $x_n$ are unit vectors.
Now, let $M \subset X$ be a closed subspace. We need to prove $T(M)$ is closed. Observe that $T(M) = T(M \cap \mathrm{ker}(T|_M)^\perp)$. If $M \cap \mathrm{ker}(T|_M)^\perp = \{0\}$, the result is immediate. Otherwise, $M \cap \mathrm{ker}(T|_M)^\perp$ is a nontrivial closed subspace that intersects with $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ trivially. By the above, $P(M \cap \mathrm{ker}(T|_M)^\perp) \subset \mathrm{ker}(T)^\perp$ is closed. But then $T$, restricted to $\mathrm{ker}(T)^\perp$, is an isomorphism, so,
$$T(M) = T(M \cap \mathrm{ker}(T|_M)^\perp) = T(P(M \cap \mathrm{ker}(T|_M)^\perp))$$
is closed. So, to summarize: Under the assumption that $T$ has closed range, $T(M)$ is closed for all closed subspaces $M$ of $X$ iff either $\mathrm{im}(T)$ or $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ is finite-dimensional.

Thank you for the thoughtful answer! I appreciate it a lot.
